# SQL script stops running after trigger introduced

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am designing a fictional database for a bank and I am required to write trigger that keeps tabs of the total loan amount that each bank-branch loans out. Here is my load file:

```
CREATE TABLE a2_bank (
routing_code   VARCHAR(200)  PRIMARY KEY,
name          VARCHAR(200)  NOT NULL,
address       VARCHAR(200)  NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO a2_bank VALUES
( '123456','ASB', '3 gladstone rd');
INSERT INTO a2_bank VALUES
( '123556','BNZ', '5 gladstone rd');
INSERT INTO a2_bank VALUES
( '12456','KIWIBANK', '3 gladstone rd');


CREATE TABLE a2_bankbranch (
name           VARCHAR(200)  NOT NULL,
branch_num     VARCHAR(200) PRIMARY KEY,
address        VARCHAR(200)  NOT NULL,
routing_code   VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
total_loan     NUMBER(38),
FOREIGN KEY(routing_code) REFERENCES a2_bank(routing_code)
);


INSERT INTO a2_bankbranch VALUES
( 'ASB', '5', '3 gladstone rd', '123456', '');
INSERT INTO a2_bankbranch VALUES
( 'ASB', '4', '28 stevee rd', '123456', '');

CREATE TABLE a2_loan (
loan_num       CHAR(10)  PRIMARY KEY,
type           VARCHAR(200)  NOT NULL,
amount         NUMBER(38)  NOT NULL,
contract_date  DATE          NOT NULL,
branch_num     VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
routing_code   VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(routing_code) REFERENCES a2_bank(routing_code),
FOREIGN KEY(branch_num) REFERENCES a2_bankbranch(branch_num)
);
@trig.sql
INSERT INTO a2_loan VALUES
( '323', 'Mortgage', '2000000', TO_DATE('11-03-1994', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), '5', '123456' );
INSERT INTO a2_loan VALUES
( '33', 'Car', '2000', TO_DATE('12-08-1994', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), '5', '123456' );
INSERT INTO a2_loan VALUES
( '3243', 'Pesonal', '875', TO_DATE('14-06-1994', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), '5', '123456' );
INSERT INTO a2_loan VALUES
( '6', 'Mortgage', '400500', TO_DATE('11-06-1994', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), '5', '123456'  );

CREATE TABLE a2_account (
acc_num       CHAR(10)  PRIMARY KEY,
type           VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
balance         VARCHAR(10)  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO a2_account VALUES
( '2539267332', 'Savings', '20');
INSERT INTO a2_account VALUES
( '8237893378', 'Cash', '300');
INSERT INTO a2_account VALUES
( '2378723936', 'Cheque', '75');
INSERT INTO a2_account VALUES
( '2378723937', 'Savings', '175');


CREATE TABLE a2_customer (
ird_num         CHAR(8)  PRIMARY KEY,
name            VARCHAR(200)  NOT NULL,
address         VARCHAR(200)  NOT NULL,
phone           VARCHAR(20)
);
INSERT INTO a2_customer VALUES
( '25362672',  'Stan Yel', '5 Wanna way', '02010201');
INSERT INTO a2_customer VALUES
( '83783783', 'Cam Birch', '34 Trada st', '02302020202');
INSERT INTO a2_customer VALUES
( '23723367', 'Jeff King', '5 Queens st', '38982383');
INSERT INTO a2_customer VALUES
( '54637822',  'John Smith', '24 Queen st', '38922383');


CREATE TABLE a2_accr (
ird_num                CHAR(8)  NOT NULL ,
account_num            CHAR(10)  NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(ird_num) REFERENCES a2_customer(ird_num),
FOREIGN KEY(account_num) REFERENCES a2_account(acc_num)
);
INSERT INTO a2_accr VALUES
( '25362672', '2539267332');
INSERT INTO a2_accr VALUES
( '83783783', '8237893378');
INSERT INTO a2_accr VALUES
( '83783783', '2378723937');

CREATE TABLE a2_loanr (
ird_num                CHAR(8)  NOT NULL ,
loan_num            CHAR(10)  NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(ird_num) REFERENCES a2_customer(ird_num),
FOREIGN KEY(loan_num) REFERENCES a2_loan(loan_num)
);
INSERT INTO a2_loanr VALUES
( '54637822', '323');
INSERT INTO a2_loanr VALUES
( '23723367', '33');

COMMIT;
```

Here is my trigger in order to achieve the desired result:

```
-- Create a trigger that will update the total loan amount
--that each bank brach may have

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ttl
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON a2_loan
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF INSERTING 
THEN
UPDATE a2_bankbranch
SET total_loan = nvl(total_loan,0) + :new.amount
WHERE routing_code = :new.routing_code
AND branch_num   = :new.branch_num;
END IF;

IF UPDATING
THEN
UPDATE a2_bankbranch
SET total_loan = nvl(total_loan,0) - :old.amount
WHERE routing_code = :old.routing_code
AND branch_num   = :old.branch_num;

UPDATE a2_bankbranch
SET total_loan = nvl(total_loan,0) + :new.amount
WHERE routing_code = :new.routing_code
AND branch_num   = :new.branch_num;
END IF;

IF DELETING
THEN
UPDATE a2_bankbranch
SET total_loan = nvl(total_loan,0) - :old.amount
WHERE routing_code = :old.routing_code
AND branch_num   = :old.branch_num;
END IF;
END;
```

Currently when I run my load.sql script in Oracle it gets down to where I am trying to introduce my trig.sql and it simply stops and comes up with the line that the trig.sql is on. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are using SQL*Plus to run this script.
In such case, you need

```
/
```

at the end of trig.sql (just single slash in a new line)
This symbol should end each PL/SQL block (procedure, function, package, trigger,  ...) in the script to execute it.